# DbUnit excel nullable foreign key

Tags: unit-testing, dbunit

I'm trying to set a nullable `BIGINT` foreign key in my excel file to fill the data for my `DbUnit` test, but I'm getting the following exception when leaving the cell empty:

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TypeCastException: Unable to typecast value <> of type <java.lang.String> to BIGINT
```

I've set the input in excel to number etc but it didn't help.

tried:

```
[NULL], [null], <null>
```

Same exception expect the "value " changes ofc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with adding:

```
ReplacementDataSet replacedDataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(dataSet); 
replacedDataSet.addReplacementObject("[NULL]", null);
```

Comment: And I fixed it by replacing `"[NULL]"` with `"[null]"`